# Testing null or empty string with this construction: s is null or ""

Tags: c#, string, null

I am very perplexed by a piece of code I came across :

```
string s = "this is my dummy string, it could be anything";

if (s is null or "") { // ???
   DoSomething();
}
```

I have never seen a string being tested in that manner.
I've always only seen this :

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
```

I've tried googling it but the keywords involved are too generic to find any relevant result.

So, what do you think? Is this a fancy new efficient way of testing strings, or is it just some quirky habit?

Comment: They're essentially doing the same thing. `s is null or ""` has only been valid syntax since C#9: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements

Comment: A good reference for C# keywords is [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/), under [Contextual keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/#contextual-keywords) you'll find the [`or`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns) keyword

Comment: I still prefer to just use a custom extension ‘s.IsNullOrEmpty()’

Comment: Yeah, don't use the "clever" code - it's not as clear or performant as `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a good judgement about the performance.

I write these codes and run them separately.

The result is insightful

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        
        string s = "this is my dummy string, it could be anything";
        
        var d1 = DateTime.Now;
        for(var i=0; i<1000000000;i++)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello Again");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Method1: " + (DateTime.Now - d1).TotalMilliseconds);
        
        
        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }
}
```

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        
        string s = "this is my dummy string, it could be anything";
        
        var d2 = DateTime.Now;
        for(var i=0; i<1000000000;i++)
        {
            if (s is null or "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello Again");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Method2: " + (DateTime.Now - d2).TotalMilliseconds);
        
        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }
}
```

Result (Duration in miliseconds):

Method1: 2959.476

Method2: 4676.6368

Comment: Use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) for benchmarking, rather than rolling your own.

Comment: @canton7 thanks for the hint, I just want to write a simple sample code, StopWatch also can be used, thanks anyway.

Comment: @canton7 Console.WriteLine("Hello Again"); will never run in this sample codes, it can be any instruction, and other Console.WriteLines are not measured in the test.

Comment: @canton7 do you think his benchmarking method invalidates the result or can I accept that "is null or string.Empty" is about twice slower than string.isNullOrEmpty ?

Answer (score 0):

They're effectively the same:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-5.0#remarks

**Remarks**

> IsNullOrEmpty is a **convenience** method that enables you to
> simultaneously test whether a String is null or its value is
> String.Empty. It is equivalent to the following code:

```
bool TestForNullOrEmpty(string s)
{
    bool result;
    result = s == null || s == string.Empty;
    return result;
}

string s1 = null;
string s2 = "";
Console.WriteLine(TestForNullOrEmpty(s1));
Console.WriteLine(TestForNullOrEmpty(s2));

// The example displays the following output:
//    True
//    True
```

Comment: Microsoft are lying. `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` is actually equivalent to `result = s == null || s.Length == 0;` which is marginally faster.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Weird, I figured Microsoft would be the authority since they created the language lol.  But, I guess for the sake of simplicity I can see their reasoning for explaining it this way.